# Derivation of $SSE =S_{yy} - S_{xy}^2/S_{xx}$

Tags: regression, variance, covariance, linear-regression, sums-of-squares

I have seen this result and I am trying to figure out how to derive it from $SSE = \sum(Y_i - \hat{Y})^2$. I know that $r = \frac{s_{xy}}{\sqrt{s_{xx}s_{yy}}} $ and I have seen online to use and substitute in $ S_{xy}^2=r^2s_{xx}s_{yy}$ but I am not sure where to do that or how to represent $SSE$ as a sum of squares.

Answer (score 0):

the key point is, in regression analysis:
$$r^2 = \frac{SSR}{SST} = \frac{L_{xy}^2}{L_{xx}L_{yy}} = \frac{S_{xy}^2}{S_{xx}S_{yy}}$$
hence to prove:
$$SSE = L_{yy} - \frac{L_{xy}^2}{L_{xx}}$$
is to prove:
$$SSE = L_{yy} - \frac{r^2 L_{xx} L_{yy}}{L_{xx}}$$
$$SSE = L_{yy} - r^2 L_{yy}$$
$$SSE = (1 - r^2) L_{yy}$$
$$SSE = (1 - \frac{SSR}{SST}) L_{yy}$$
$$SSE =  \frac{SST - SSR}{SST} L_{yy}$$
by
$$SST = SSR + SSE$$
hence
$$SSE =  \frac{SSE}{SST} L_{yy} $$
notice that
$$SST = L_{yy} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar y)^2$$
hence
$$SSE = SSE$$
$$Q.E.D$$

also be aware of the difference between $L_{yy}$ and $S_{yy}$
$$S_{yy} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar y)^2$$
$$S_{xy} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar y)  (x_i - \bar x)$$
however
$$L_{yy} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar y)^2$$
$$L_{xy} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar y)  (x_i - \bar x)$$
which means
$$L_{yy} = (n - 1)S_{yy}$$
$$L_{xx} = (n - 1)S_{xx}$$
$$L_{xy} = (n - 1)S_{xy}$$
but
$$r^2 = \frac{L_{xy}^2}{L_{xx}L_{yy}} = \frac{S_{xy}^2}{S_{xx}S_{yy}}$$
holds since you can get rid of all coefficents